# A question about homeomorphism on $D^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Using singular homology, how to show that for any homeomorphism $h\colon D^n \to D^n$ , $h(S^{n-1})=S^{n-1}$ ?

Where $D^n:=\{x \in \mathbb R^n :\|x\|\le 1\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to consider the local homology groups
$H_n(D^n,D^n-\{x\})$ for $x\in D_n$. These vanish for $x$ on the boundary,
but are cyclic for $x$ in the interior. An auto-homeomorphism $h$ induced
an isomorphism between $H_n(D^n,D^n-\{x\}) $ and $H_n(D^n,D^n-\{h(x)\})$.
So it maps the boundary to the boundary and the interior to the interior.

Comment: why does it vanish on the boundary ? If $x$ is on the boundary then is $D^n - \{x\}$ homotopic  to $D^n$ ?

Comment: I haven't seen that proof before, usually its derived as a corollary of the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: From the long exact sequence, it's isomorphic to $\widetilde H_{n-1}(D_n-\{x\})=0$ as that space is contractible.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : basically that's exactly what I was asking ... whether $D^n - \{x\}$ is homotopic to $D^n$ or not i.e. whether  $D^n - \{x\}$ is contractible or not ... anyway I think I can show $D^n - \{x\}$ is convex , so I have no more doubts about your solution